# Setting select box selected value from session values

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, select

I have a search section on my Codeigniter page which has 6 select boxes. When the form first submitted, controller assigns the selected values to session variables.

I want to make the values to be selected on the new page. I try to minimize the usage of PHP on my views. I searched for it on the internet but could not find good examples. I would like to learn most efficient or common way of doing this with CodeIgniter.

Comment: We will need to see what you have tried so far.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (to avoid alot of conditional logic) is to make sure your select box is generated by the form helper `form_dropdown()` pass the array of options and then pass the selected option *value* from the session var which in this example is called `selectbox`.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$options = array(
        'small'         => 'Small Shirt',
        'med'           => 'Medium Shirt',
        'large'         => 'Large Shirt',
        'xlarge'        => 'Extra Large Shirt',
);
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, $this->session->selectbox);
```

More on that here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_dropdown

Comment: Did you mean `$this->session->userdata('selectbox')` you were missing userdata

Comment: nope https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data see "magic getter"

Comment: Learn something new every day.